# Do I need visa for Ireland if I have a Spanish Blue Card?

Tags: visas, ireland

Little bit lost here, need your advice.
I have Spanish Blue Card, I am citizen of Russia, and I want to travel to Republic of Ireland. 
Do I need visa? As I understand that Republic of Ireland is not member of Schengen, but the member of EU.
According to this I need visa, am I correct?
http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html

Comment: You have an official Irish government source that says you need a visa and you're asking us whether you need a visa.  Is there something specific about the page you linked to that you do not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=RU&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IE&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C):

> National **Russian Fed. (RU)**
>   Destination **Ireland (Rep.) (IE)**
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid for the period of intended stay.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Russian Fed. with a 
>   valid "C" visa issued by the United Kingdom if they have first entered
>   the United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 90 days or until the end of
>   the period of stay granted in the United

Therefore the answer is **yes**, you do need an Irish visa. The only exceptions are for holders of UK visas, although having a valid Blue Card would make it much easier to receive an Irish visa.